# Google Guice update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, guice

I am trying to use com.google.inject in my application. Initialy I added as a jar, but now that I am building my application I need Guice to be part of my target definition. What is Google Guice update site URL that I can use in my target definition?

Comment: Update sites are only available for code which provides Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand. I thought that there might be a plugin that wraps Guice into update site. How would I then use Google Guice in my Eclipse Plugin? Should I just do it myself? I rather rely on "official" source.

Comment: You can make your own plugin or just use a jar. Also be careful because Eclipse 4.x has its own injection code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a build tool like maven or gradle, you can include it as a dependency. For example, here's how you could do it with `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0'
```

This will pull in javax.inject which has the standard inject annotation, as a dependency.

Comment: Clearly, the OP is building an Eclipse plug-in and is not using a build driven by Maven or Gradle. This is indicated by the statements/questions "I need Guice to be part of my target definition" and "What is Google Guice update site URL that I can use in my target definition?".
@RomainBernard's suggestion to use the update site for Eclipse Orbit is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the xtext 'orbit' update-site, which contains google inject :

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <unit id="com.google.guava" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="com.google.inject" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.apache.log4j" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.aopalliance" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.easymock" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.antlr.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.inject" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.apache.ant" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="org.objectweb.asm" version="0.0.0"/>
    <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180606145124/repository/"/>
</location>
```

Comment: should be download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180606145124/repository/